# A one to many relationship creating a dynamic link between product and owner

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

So essentially I am trying to view the profile of the person who uploaded the product that I am currently viewing using a foreign key in the tables.The profile exists and the foreign key in the products table matches the primary key of the admin table, I am quite new to SQL and cannot figure out the query that I need to assign to the variable to insert into the href link. Here are the two tables:

admin:

- caterer_id
- username
- password
- last_log_date
- biography
- country
- state

products:

- product_id
- product_name
- price
- category
- details
- date_added
- caterer_id

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN admin ON admin.caterer_id = products.caterer_id
```

You will get the data from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an ORM such as [DataMapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/). However, if you really want to write out all the SQL yourself, you will need to use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Joins have a direction (`LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `LEFT INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT INNER JOIN`), so you'll need to decide where to start and where to finish.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from admin a left join products p  on a.caterer_id = p.caterer_id
```

check out jsfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b69/2/0